# Tree View JavaFX Memory out of Space

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2

I have created javaFX tree with custom Objects (SystemNode). 
Tree Items has graphics: check-box and image icon which I have set through updateItems() method.

Whenever I expand or collapse Item in tree ,twice or thrice I get JAVA HEAP MEMORY OUT OF SPACE and whole UI hangs UP.

PS: updateItems() method is invoked every time I expand or collapse tree node
I have tried adding event handlers but they didn't work.

Can anyone give some solutions.

Here is how I set cellFactory :

```
treeView_technicalAreas.setCellFactory(Util.getTreeCellFactory());
```

Here is code for cell factory:

```
public static Callback<TreeView<SystemNode>, TreeCell<SystemNode>> getTreeCellFactory() {
    Callback<TreeView<SystemNode>, TreeCell<SystemNode>> callback = new Callback<TreeView<SystemNode>, TreeCell<SystemNode>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeCell<SystemNode> call(TreeView<SystemNode> p) {
            TreeCell<SystemNode> cell = new TreeCell<SystemNode>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(SystemNode t, boolean isEmpty) {
                    super.updateItem(t, isEmpty); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    if (!isEmpty) {
                        System.out.println("util call back : " + t.getSystem().getName());
                        setText(t.getSystem().getName());
                        HBox hBox = new HBox();

                        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                        checkBox.setSelected(t.getSelected());
                        checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(t.getSelectedProperty());
                        hBox.setSpacing(SPACING_BETWEEN_ICON_AND_CHECKBOX);
                        ImageView imageView_icon = null;

                        if (t.getSystem().getType() == TYPE.BAREA) {
                            imageView_icon = new ImageView(Constant.Image_AREAS);
                        } else if (t.getSystem().getType() == TYPE.AREA) {
                            imageView_icon = new ImageView(Constant.Image_AREAS);
                        } else if (t.getSystem().getType() == TYPE.DOCUMENT) {
                            imageView_icon = new ImageView(Constant.Image_DOCUMENTS);
                        } else if (t.getSystem().getType() == TYPE.NOUN_NAME) {
                            imageView_icon = new ImageView(Constant.Image_NOUN_NAME);
                        } else if (t.getSystem().getType() == TYPE.CHANGE) {
                            imageView_icon = new ImageView(Constant.Image_DCC);
                        } else if (t.getSystem().getType() == TYPE.TASK) {
                            imageView_icon = new ImageView(Constant.Image_TASK);
                        }

                        hBox.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, imageView_icon);
                        setGraphic(hBox);
                    }
                }
            };

            return cell;
        }
    };

    return callback;
}
```

Comment: how many elements do your tree may have?

Comment: currently less than 15 elements.But It wll have 30+ nodes in future.